# Embedded Jetty 9.4.X WebApp wont start with Java 11

Tags: java, jersey, java-11, embedded-jetty

I am running an embedded Jetty 9.4.33 and using Jre 11.0.8
When I try to start my application, jetty throws the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.async.AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl cannot be cast to class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.spi.AsyncContextDelegateProvider (org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.async.AsyncContextDelegateProviderImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.spi.AsyncContextDelegateProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @2eda2062)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.getAsyncExtensionDelegate(WebComponent.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:346)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:739)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at com.sample.jetty.RunJetty.main(RunJetty.java:132)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your `com.sample.jetty.RunJetty` code to setup/initialize your jetty and associated WebAppContext.

Comment: Hard to help without more information.  Along with the details of RunJetty, the dependencies you are using and what versions of them are equally important to know.